# Why is worksheetfunction.index() so slow on arrays vs on a range? Is there an even faster way?

Tags: excel, vba

I have noticed that performing worksheetfunction.index() on a 30,000 x 8 Double array is about 20-30x slower than on a 30,000 x 8 range in a worksheet.

i.e.

```
Dim rngIlfParams As Range
Set rngIlfParams = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PureILF Params").Range("PureIlfParams")
dblIlfLower = WorksheetFunction.Index(rngIlfParams, lngRowLower, lngCol)
```

is way faster than:

```
Dim dblPureIlfParams() As Double
'etc: populate dblPureIlfParams with a 30,000 x 8 matrix
dblIlfLower = WorksheetFunction.Index(dblIlfParams, lngRowLower, lngCol)
```

I was surprised by this and wondering if there was an even faster way to do large index/matches.

Comment: Not sure why you'd use `Index` at all in this case. Just `dblPureIlfParams(lngRowLower, lngCol)`. Note that `Match` is definitely slower when used on an array, vs. on a range. You can always just loop if you need to find a match.

Comment: Worksheet functions are optimized for working on worksheet ranges - if you use them for anything else they are much slower than the equivalent operation using VBA.  Even something like `a = Application.Sum(x, y)` is an order of magnitude slower than `a = x + y` for example

Comment: @BigBen Sorry yes it's actually the Match part of the code (which I haven't included to keep it concise) that was causing the problem.  You are right I could/should have not used WorksheetFunction.Index.  Using .Match on the range is fast enough, so I haven't investigated whether a loop would be even faster.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments above.  It turns out my misapprehension came from the fact that I was in the habit of putting everything into arrays because I thought it sped everything up.  It turns out this behaviour is only encouraged when you are performing a loop because looping over ranges is very slow.

I am used to Python where manipulating matrices is much easier, but for this project I was restricted to using VBA.